# Do gerrit code review support .gitattributes settings?

Tags: git, gerrit

do gerrit code review support .gitattributes? Does it support unset diff of files? Is there a setting that needs to be activated to enable it ? I tried unsetting diff on some files, it works fine on git diff, but still shows the diff on the change.

Comment: I think Gerrit doesn't support .gitattributes... but I'm not sure.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this "unset diff"?

Comment: to merge by ignoring changes on generated (minified) code.